# Why the icon identification's field is a '?' and not 't' like the official example is?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new on Kibana.

I have the following problem: The fields that I send to elasticsearch by logstash can not be used in many situations on "Visualizes" and I note that they are marked with a '?' and not a 't' like the official fields.

By official fields I refer to that defined by

```
filter => {message => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
```

on logstash.conf.

When I use:

```
filter => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timelog} %{INT:id} %{QUOTEDSTRING:status} %{NUMBER:rkey} %{QUOTEDSTRING:origin} %{QUOTEDSTRING:resource} %{QUOTEDSTRING:result} %{QUOTEDSTRING:statuselastic} %{QUOTEDSTRING:statusmongo} %{QUOTEDSTRING:statusmkp} %{QUOTEDSTRING:my_message} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:created_at} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:last_update}"}
```

So, my fields come marked with '?' and can not be used on "Visualizes".

Here is the prints:

[image: Official fields]

[image]

**I already try use "mapping" to set "type" property. But without success.
I tried edit the fields on "Management" -> "Index Patterns" too, but the fields marked by '?' also are not there.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the settings for the index and hit the reload button in the upper right corner (right next to the red trashcan -- it says refresh field list if you hover over it).  If fields are added to an index after you add it to kibana, kibana does not automatically see the new fields.  You have to let it know that something has changed.